# Loop through excel files and copy the same cells to an empty cell in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have many excel files in a folder. I have macros that loop through each file and copy N2 and O2 in a application called CopyMyStuff.

I am trying to paste this is another excel workbook that i open in a new row each time. It only works when it opens all the workbooks in that looping folder. It will not work when i try to close those workbooks.

`Workbooks(MyFile).Close savechanges:=True`

this is giving me the problem. If i take it out it works but I'm left with 50 sheets open that I have to close.

```
Sub Loop_1()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    'Adding New Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
    'Saving the Workbook
    wkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\mscarpa\Documents\Automation\COMPILER.xlsx"
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!CopyMyStuff"
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close savechanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir

        With wkb
            Set wkst = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
            wkst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Error I get is

> paste special method of range class failed.

Comment: on what line do you get the error?

Comment: im not 100% sure, when i step through the code i get the pop up error message after i pick my folder i want to loop through. but again for some reason if i take Workbooks(MyFile).Close savechanges:=True out it all works fine

Comment: What's the error you get when you pick the folders? That's where the problem is

Comment: Your `MyFile` refers to a folder not a file.